# Difference in bit vectors

Tags: algorithms, bit-manipulation

I have to write an algorithm for a following problem. I have a function that has 2 parameters: an array of 32 bit unsigned whole numbers - bit vectors [*ARR*] and distance[*dist*]. We need to find how many 32 bit numbers x there are such that they are differing from each of the bit vector for the most *dist* bits.

Example: We have vectors: 0011, 0101 and 0101. When *dist*=3 then for 0000..1111 there are 13 such numbers. If *dist*=4 then the result is 16.

My idea is to do it with Levenshtein algorithm ( [example on this website](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#C.2B.2B)), so that I would convert the array into string.

But it would be too slow. I have a hint that we should look at the *ARR* and find those bits that are same in every number and therefore we need not compare them.

> "For example, we have specified bit vectors with 18 fixed bits (ie we
>   will test a total of 2 on (32-18) values) and we have given *dist* =
>   6. If you calculate for a value of x, which varies from the modified bit vectors in 6 bits, you will count just one. If it differs in less
>   bits, for example in 5 bits, then you count 19 times (4 differences -
>   172x, 3 differences - 988x, ...). Think about the combinatorial
>   problem here."

I have trouble understanding that part. Can someone please explain this to me and give me a suggestion in which direction to go?